# Как предать boolean параметр в NavController?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigationcontroller

Есть вот такой метод в активити который открывает фрагмент по Uri

```
...
    fun navigate(uri: Uri, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        with(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment) {
            val authGraph: NavGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.auth_nav_graph)
            maybeSetIapNavGraphs(navHostFragment.navController, authGraph)
            navController.graph = authGraph

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                navController.popBackStack()
                navController.navigate(uri)
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Мне нужно передать boolean фрагменту который будет открываться. Судя по параметрам которые принимает `navigate` в паре с Uri может быть только `NavOptions`, но `NavOptions` не принимает `Bundle`.

Вопрос, как передать boolean в этом случае?

**UPD**

Я попробовал еще вот так

```
...
    fun navigate(uri: Uri, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        with(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment) {
            val authGraph: NavGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.auth_nav_graph)
            maybeSetIapNavGraphs(navHostFragment.navController, authGraph)

            val bundle = Bundle().apply { putInt("isEnabled", 1) }
            navController.setGraph(authGraph, bundle)

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                navController.popBackStack()
                navController.navigate(uri)
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Но когда я пробую получить это значение во фрагменте

```
val arg1Value = requireArguments().getInt("isEnabled")
```

я получаю `0`